# AVR USART OUTPUT almost similar as input

Tags: usb, avr, atmega, uart

My output is different from my input when I try to read it from my Hercules terminal. Could this be from a bad UART initialization?

Inputs : | á, 1, 123

Outputs:|a, ±, ±²³

Code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000 // 1 Mhz
#endif

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE ((( F_CPU / ( USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL ))) - 1)

int main (void)
{
    char ReceivedByte ;
    UCSRB = (1 << RXEN ) | (1 << TXEN ); // Turn on the transmission and reception circuitry
    UCSRC = (1 << URSEL ) | (1 << UCSZ0 ) | (1 << UCSZ1 ); // Use 8-bit character sizes
    UBRRH = ( BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8) ; // Load upper 8-bits of the baud rate value into the high byte
                                    //of the UBRR register
    UBRRL = BAUD_PRESCALE ; // Load lower 8 -bits of the baud rate value into the low byte of the
    //UBRR register
    for (;;) // Loop forever
    {
    while (( UCSRA & (1 << RXC )) == 0) {}; // Do nothing until data have been received and is
    //ready to be read from UDR
    ReceivedByte = UDR ; // Fetch the received byte value into the variable "ByteReceived"
while (( UCSRA & (1 << UDRE )) == 0) {}; // Do nothing until UDR is ready for more data to
//be written to it
UDR = ReceivedByte ; // Echo back the received byte back to the computer
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using approximate numbers for 9600 with a 1MHz clock 1000000 / 9600 / 16 = 6.51 which will be truncated to 6 and then dropped to 5 once 1 is subtracted. You can see you lose a lot of precision when the divisor numbers are that small as they are converted to an integer. There is a calculator here you may find useful:

[WormFood's AVR Baud Rate Calculator](http://www.wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php)

That shows an error of 7.5% which is too high, you'll need more like 5% for reliable operation if the device it's connected to is very accurate, but I normally like to aim for a 2% or lower error. The alternatives that come to mind are changing your crystal frequency (or turn off the `CKDIV8` fuse if you're using it) or to choose a baud rate such as 4800 that has an acceptable error margin at that clock rate.

Although looking at the table further (by clicking the relevant checkbox) another option would be to use the `U2X=1` mode that doubles the effective UART clock rate that would drop the error to 0.2%. In that case your code should include:

```
#define BAUD_PRESCALE ((( F_CPU / ( USART_BAUDRATE * 8UL ))) - 1)
UCSRA |= (1 << U2X);
```

That does cause the receiver to sample half as often to it may not quite be as reliable but might be an option if there's a reason you don't want to increase the clock rate.

Comment: How do you know that 5 is bad?

Comment: It's just because the difference between 5 and 5.51 is quite large as a percentage. Say you used a 10MHz clock it would be 65.1 - 1 = 64.1, and the difference between 64 and 64.1 is much smaller as a percentage.